# WooCommerce Order Status Displays Twice on Order Page

Tags: plugins, actions

I modified the woocommerce_custom_order_columns function to make some changes to the WooCommerce Admin Order page. Everything works great, except that Order Status shows up twice (but only for the latest (top) order). I've attached an image and the code that could be causing this. I have no idea what would make this happen.

[image]

My Code:

```
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'match_order_woocommerce_custom_order_columns', 2);

function match_order_woocommerce_custom_order_columns( $column ) {

remove_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'woocommerce_custom_order_columns', 2);

global $post, $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order( $post->ID );

switch ($column) {
    case "order_status" :

        printf( '<mark class="%s">%s</mark>', sanitize_title($order->status), __($order->status, 'woocommerce') );

    break;
    case "order_title" :

        if ($order->user_id) $user_info = get_userdata($order->user_id);

        if (isset($user_info) && $user_info) :

            $user = '<a href="user-edit.php?user_id=' . esc_attr( $user_info->ID ) . '">';

            if ($user_info->first_name || $user_info->last_name) $user .= $user_info->first_name.' '.$user_info->last_name;
            else $user .= esc_html( $user_info->display_name );

            $user .= '</a>';

        else :
            $user = __('Guest', 'woocommerce');
        endif;

        echo '<a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&action=edit').'"><strong>'.sprintf( __('Order %s', 'woocommerce'), $order->get_order_number() ).'</strong></a> ' . __('made by', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . $user;

        if ($order->billing_email) :
            echo '<small class="meta">'.__('Email:', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . '<a href="' . esc_url( 'mailto:'.$order->billing_email ).'">'.esc_html( $order->billing_email ).'</a></small>';
        endif;
        if ($order->billing_phone) :
            echo '<small class="meta">'.__('Tel:', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . esc_html( $order->billing_phone ) . '</small>';
        endif;

    break;
    case "billing_address" :
        if ($order->get_formatted_billing_address()) :

            echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . esc_url( 'http://maps.google.com/maps?&q='.urlencode( $order->get_billing_address() ).'&z=16' ) . '">'. preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', ', ', $order->get_formatted_billing_address()) .'</a>';
        else :
            echo '&ndash;';
        endif;

        if ($order->payment_method_title) :
            echo '<small class="meta">' . __('Via', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . esc_html( $order->payment_method_title ) . '</small>';
        endif;

    break;
    case "shipping_address" :
        if ($order->get_formatted_shipping_address()) :

            echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . esc_url( 'http://maps.google.com/maps?&q='.urlencode( $order->get_shipping_address() ).'&z=16' ) .'">'. preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', ', ', $order->get_formatted_shipping_address()) .'</a>';
        else :
            echo '&ndash;';
        endif;

        if ($order->shipping_method_title) :
            echo '<small class="meta">' . __('Via', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . esc_html( $order->shipping_method_title ) . '</small>';
        endif;
    break;
    case "total_cost" :
        echo $order->get_formatted_order_total();
    break;
    case "order_date" :

        if ( '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $post->post_date ) :
            $t_time = $h_time = __( 'Unpublished', 'woocommerce' );
        else :
            $t_time = get_the_time( __( 'Y/m/d g:i:s A', 'woocommerce' ), $post );

            $gmt_time = strtotime($post->post_date_gmt);
            $time_diff = current_time('timestamp', 1) - $gmt_time;

            if ( $time_diff > 0 && $time_diff < 24*60*60 )
                $h_time = sprintf( __( '%s ago', 'woocommerce' ), human_time_diff( $gmt_time, current_time('timestamp', 1) ) );
            else
                $h_time = get_the_time( __( 'Y/m/d', 'woocommerce' ), $post );
        endif;

        echo '<abbr title="' . $t_time . '">' . apply_filters( 'post_date_column_time', $h_time, $post ) . '</abbr>';

    break;
    case "order_actions" :

        ?><p>
            <?php
                do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_start', $order );

                $actions = array();

                if ( in_array( $order->status, array( 'pending', 'on-hold' ) ) )
                    $actions[] = array(
                        'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce-mark-order-processing&order_id=' . $post->ID ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-processing' ),
                        'name'      => __( 'Processing', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'action'    => "processing"
                    );

                if ( in_array( $order->status, array( 'pending', 'on-hold', 'processing' ) ) )
                    $actions[] = array(
                        'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce-mark-order-complete&order_id=' . $post->ID ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-complete' ),
                        'name'      => __( 'Complete', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'action'    => "complete"
                    );

                $actions[] = array(
                        'url'       => admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $post->ID . '&action=edit' ),
                        'name'      => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'action'    => "view"
                    );

                $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', $actions, $order );

                foreach ( $actions as $action )
                    printf( '<a class="button tips" href="%s" data-tip="%s"><img src="%s" alt="%s" width="14" /></a>', $action['url'], $action['name'], $woocommerce->plugin_url() . '/assets/images/icons/' . $action['action'] . '.png', $action['name'] );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end', $order );
            ?>
        </p><?php

    break;
    case "note" :
        if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'match_order' , TRUE) == 1 ) {
            echo '<img src="' . WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/match_previous_order/note-red.png" alt="Match Previous Order" class="tips" data-tip="'. __('Match Previous Order', 'woocommerce') .'" width="14" height="14" />';
        }
        else if ($order->customer_note) {
            echo '<img src="'.$woocommerce->plugin_url().'/assets/images/note.png" alt="yes" class="tips" data-tip="'. __('Yes', 'woocommerce') .'" width="14" height="14" />';
        }
        else {
            echo '<img src="'.$woocommerce->plugin_url().'/assets/images/note-off.png" alt="no" class="tips" data-tip="'. __('No', 'woocommerce') .'" width="14" height="14" />';
        }
    break;
    case "order_comments" :

        echo '<div class="post-com-count-wrapper">
            <a href="'. admin_url('post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&action=edit') .'" class="post-com-count"><span class="comment-count">'. $post->comment_count .'</span></a>
            </div>';
    break;
}
}
```

The WooCommerce Code:

```
function woocommerce_custom_order_columns( $column ) {

global $post, $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order( $post->ID );

switch ($column) {
    case "order_status" :

        printf( '<mark class="%s">%s</mark>', sanitize_title($order->status), __($order->status, 'woocommerce') );

    break;
    case "order_title" :

        if ($order->user_id) $user_info = get_userdata($order->user_id);

        if (isset($user_info) && $user_info) :

            $user = '<a href="user-edit.php?user_id=' . esc_attr( $user_info->ID ) . '">';

            if ($user_info->first_name || $user_info->last_name) $user .= $user_info->first_name.' '.$user_info->last_name;
            else $user .= esc_html( $user_info->display_name );

            $user .= '</a>';

        else :
            $user = __('Guest', 'woocommerce');
        endif;

        echo '<a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&action=edit').'"><strong>'.sprintf( __('Order %s', 'woocommerce'), $order->get_order_number() ).'</strong></a> ' . __('made by', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . $user;

        if ($order->billing_email) :
            echo '<small class="meta">'.__('Email:', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . '<a href="' . esc_url( 'mailto:'.$order->billing_email ).'">'.esc_html( $order->billing_email ).'</a></small>';
        endif;
        if ($order->billing_phone) :
            echo '<small class="meta">'.__('Tel:', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . esc_html( $order->billing_phone ) . '</small>';
        endif;

    break;
    case "billing_address" :
        if ($order->get_formatted_billing_address()) :

            echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . esc_url( 'http://maps.google.com/maps?&q='.urlencode( $order->get_billing_address() ).'&z=16' ) . '">'. preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', ', ', $order->get_formatted_billing_address()) .'</a>';
        else :
            echo '&ndash;';
        endif;

        if ($order->payment_method_title) :
            echo '<small class="meta">' . __('Via', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . esc_html( $order->payment_method_title ) . '</small>';
        endif;

    break;
    case "shipping_address" :
        if ($order->get_formatted_shipping_address()) :

            echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . esc_url( 'http://maps.google.com/maps?&q='.urlencode( $order->get_shipping_address() ).'&z=16' ) .'">'. preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', ', ', $order->get_formatted_shipping_address()) .'</a>';
        else :
            echo '&ndash;';
        endif;

        if ($order->shipping_method_title) :
            echo '<small class="meta">' . __('Via', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . esc_html( $order->shipping_method_title ) . '</small>';
        endif;
    break;
    case "total_cost" :
        echo $order->get_formatted_order_total();
    break;
    case "order_date" :

        if ( '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $post->post_date ) :
            $t_time = $h_time = __( 'Unpublished', 'woocommerce' );
        else :
            $t_time = get_the_time( __( 'Y/m/d g:i:s A', 'woocommerce' ), $post );

            $gmt_time = strtotime($post->post_date_gmt);
            $time_diff = current_time('timestamp', 1) - $gmt_time;

            if ( $time_diff > 0 && $time_diff < 24*60*60 )
                $h_time = sprintf( __( '%s ago', 'woocommerce' ), human_time_diff( $gmt_time, current_time('timestamp', 1) ) );
            else
                $h_time = get_the_time( __( 'Y/m/d', 'woocommerce' ), $post );
        endif;

        echo '<abbr title="' . $t_time . '">' . apply_filters( 'post_date_column_time', $h_time, $post ) . '</abbr>';

    break;
    case "order_actions" :

        ?><p>
            <?php
                do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_start', $order );

                $actions = array();

                if ( in_array( $order->status, array( 'pending', 'on-hold' ) ) )
                    $actions[] = array(
                        'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce-mark-order-processing&order_id=' . $post->ID ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-processing' ),
                        'name'      => __( 'Processing', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'action'    => "processing"
                    );

                if ( in_array( $order->status, array( 'pending', 'on-hold', 'processing' ) ) )
                    $actions[] = array(
                        'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce-mark-order-complete&order_id=' . $post->ID ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-complete' ),
                        'name'      => __( 'Complete', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'action'    => "complete"
                    );

                $actions[] = array(
                        'url'       => admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $post->ID . '&action=edit' ),
                        'name'      => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'action'    => "view"
                    );

                $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', $actions, $order );

                foreach ( $actions as $action )
                    printf( '<a class="button tips" href="%s" data-tip="%s"><img src="%s" alt="%s" width="14" /></a>', $action['url'], $action['name'], $woocommerce->plugin_url() . '/assets/images/icons/' . $action['action'] . '.png', $action['name'] );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end', $order );
            ?>
        </p><?php

    break;
    case "note" :
        if ($order->customer_note)
            echo '<img src="'.$woocommerce->plugin_url().'/assets/images/note.png" alt="yes" class="tips" data-tip="'. __('Yes', 'woocommerce') .'" width="14" height="14" />';
        else
            echo '<img src="'.$woocommerce->plugin_url().'/assets/images/note-off.png" alt="no" class="tips" data-tip="'. __('No', 'woocommerce') .'" width="14" height="14" />';

    break;
    case "order_comments" :

        echo '<div class="post-com-count-wrapper">
            <a href="'. admin_url('post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&action=edit') .'" class="post-com-count"><span class="comment-count">'. $post->comment_count .'</span></a>
            </div>';
    break;
}
}

add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'woocommerce_custom_order_columns', 2);
```

As you can see, the only thing I've done here is remove the default `woocommerce_custom_order_columns` function and replaced it with the `match_order_woocommerce_custom_order_columns` function. Everything else is the same.

Comment: In your code, you should do `remove_action` outside of the function. Just before the `add_action`, for example.

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't work. It crashes the plugin.

Comment: Do you think that's why it's doing this, though?

Comment: You should show your full code for that custom column...

Comment: I've updated it to include the full functions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I used the plugins_loaded hook, like this:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded','example_function'); 

function example_function(){

remove_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'woocommerce_custom_order_columns', 2);
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'match_order_woocommerce_custom_order_columns', 2);

}
```